# Ejabberd archive messages even if offline

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, mongoose-im

Does ejabberd have this kind of mod? [mod_offline_stub](https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/mod_offline_stub/)

Correct me if im wrong, moongooseIM stores the messages even if `<service-unavailable/>` on mod_mam if user exists.

Does ejabberd have this kind of functionality? Basically archive the unsent messages for later retrieval. I don't want to use `mod_offline` because Flexible Offline Retrieval is only available in Business Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Recent ejabberd version stores messages in MAM before storing them offline
2. Flexible Offline Message Retrieval is available in community version actually.

Comment: is there client on windows or mac, i can test xep-0013?

Comment: it's good that it stores it in MAM, so I can just purge the unwanted stuff and only get the latest per sender